# How does each dispatcher servlet know which controllers to check, in a multi-dispatcher application?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, servlets, spring-mvc

**Background**

I am new to spring and have been looking at how the dispatcher probes @controller annotated classes and methods.

**Question**

If you can have multiple dispatcher servlets in a single web application how do you assign them to specific controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Spring 3.x, you would configure each dispatcher with its own Spring configuration file (or class). Then (assuming an XML config) in one dispatcher, you would declare:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.acme.project.foo"/>
```

and in the other dispatcher you would do:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.acme.project.bar"/>
```

That way each dispatcher would be associated with different Controllers based on their package structure.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you [Spring - Java Hunter](https://javahunter.wordpress.com/2012/09/12/spring-and-springsecurity/)